# How to get a single color from 32-bit RGB value?

Tags: java, methods, binary, bit-manipulation, operators

i'm new to coding and i'm having a bit of a problem with bitwise operators in Java. I need to create a RGB number which basically consists of the 3 8bit-binary values of the 3 different colors, and to get one of the 3 desired  values of the colors, i need to implement 3 getter-Methods, so for example if this were the binary of the rgb  00000000 01001110 10011010 11010101, getRed() would only get 00000000 **01001110** 10011010 11010101 the bold part. For this one, i took `rgb = rgb >> 16`, which worked fine, but im having trouble figuring out how to get the other two. Im only allowed to use the `&` and `>>` operators and i've tried many things, but i just can't figure it out. Thanks for any help

Comment: You should look into using a mask.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

Comment: hint: the bitmask you need to use for an 8-bit value is 255 (11111111 in binary)